# What happened to my silver border outline on my summoner profile?

Tags: league-of-legends

The silver border outline on my summoner profile for League of Legends is not showing any more during the loading screen. What happened and how can I get the silver outline back? I still have my bronze and silver trophy emblems but the silver border outline seems to have vanished into thin air.

Comment: Not much to go on but are you in the same Queue? Your border isn't the same in every Queue and maybe that's what you're getting. If not I'd send in a support ticket to see what's up.

Comment: I figured it out for the most part. You are right about how all the ques are different. My silver border only shows in ARAM, Customs, 3v3, and i heard rumor also dominion but have not tested that out yet. But I still am missing my silver for 5s too unfortunately but I'm fine without it anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you got your silver in 3v3 last season it will not show up in 5v5 que.

This is the same for all que's including ranked 5's and solo.